# How do I pass in an interface address (-I) when pinging an address with Erlang's :gen_icmp?

Tags: erlang, icmp

I want to ping an address but with the ability to set an interface address from which to ping from. Something like:

```
ping -I address1 address2
```

I am using Erlang's [`:gen_icmp.ping/3`](https://github.com/gleber/gen_icmp/blob/master/src/gen_icmp.erl#L108) function from [`gen_icmp`](https://github.com/gleber/gen_icmp) library.

Comment: I don't believe Erlang has a gen_icmp module. Are you using a dependency?

Comment: If you want to do something, don’t hesitate to do it. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the socket you pass on to `gen_icmp.ping/3` you can specify the specific interface you want to use with the `ifaddr` option. For example:

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, Port, [{ifaddr, {192,168,10,11}}])
```

The ip address you use has to be a valid interface on the host of course.